# C++ копирование в диапазоне String

Tags: c++, строки, copy

Вопросик. Как скопировать в строку диапазон другой строки? Например:

```
string two = "test1@mail.ru test2@mail.ru";

// некие действа и в итоге хочу получить это:

string one = "test1@mail.ru";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если именно просто скопировать **диапазон** - то

```
string one = two.substr(0,13);
```

Answer (score 0):

Дошло. Можно так:

```
std::copy(two.begin()+3,two.begin()+10,std::back_inserter(one));
```